# Returning null in the output

Tags: java

The method returns some null skipping some objects.The goal of the method is to return sorterd list of people according to their 'midterm' and 'final' ('midterm' of a person is immediately followed by his 'final') Could smb please help to fix it? Here's the code

```
public static Exam[] collateExams(Exam[] exams)
    {

        Exam[] r = new Exam[exams.length]; 
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; (i < exams.length) && (index < exams.length/2); i++)
        {
            if (exams[i].getExamType() == 'm')
            {
                r[index*2] = new Exam(exams[i].getFirstName(), exams[i].getLastName(), exams[i].getID(), "midterm", exams[i].getScore());
                for(int j = 0; (j < exams.length) && (index < exams.length/2); j++)
                {
                    if((exams[j].getExamType() == 'f') && (exams[i].getID() == exams[j].getID()))
                    {
                        r[index*2 + 1] = new Exam(exams[i].getFirstName(), exams[i].getLastName(), exams[i].getID(), "final", exams[i].getScore());
                    }
                }
            }
            index++;
        }
        return r;
```

here's the output:

```
null
null
Bill Gates 6 midterm  90
Bill Gates 6 final  90
James Gosling 3 midterm  100
James Gosling 3 final  100
Sergey Brin 22 midterm  98
null
Dennis Ritchie 5 midterm  94
Dennis Ritchie 5 final  94
Steve Jobs 9 midterm  95
Steve Jobs 9 final  95
```

Here's the unsorted list which is passed as a parameter:

```
Steve Jobs 9 final  91
Bill Gates 6 midterm  90
James Gosling 3 midterm  100
Sergey Brin 22 midterm  98
Dennis Ritchie 5 midterm  94
Steve Jobs 9 midterm  95
Dennis Ritchie 5 final  100
Jeff Dean 7 midterm  100
Bill Gates 6 final  96
Jeff Dean 7 final  100
Sergey Brin 27 final  97
James Gosling 3 final  100
```

Comment: Why use arrays when you can use `java.util.List`?

Comment: Also, where is the rest of the code and how you are printing these?

Comment: First entry of `terms` is `Steve Jobs 9 final  91`, so I guess `exams[i].getExamType() == 'm'` is *false*. That means it would never call `r[index*2] = ...` and it skips the indexes `0` and `1` of `r`. Now, what exactly is unclear here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your entire class is posting the same question, or you are Joshua mark II.  Now, other variations said only one for loop and other restrictions, so I am going to ignore all of that and address the messed up double loop above.  This will fix the loop above:

```
public static Exam[] collateExams(Exam[] exams)
{
     Exam[] r = new Exam[exams.length]; 
     int index = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < exams.length ; i++)
     {
         if (exams[i].getExamType() == 'm')
         {
             r[index*2] = new Exam(exams[i].getFirstName(), exams[i].getLastName(), exams[i].getID(), 'm', exams[i].getScore());
             for(int j = 0; j < exams.length; j++)
             {
                 if((exams[j].getExamType() == 'f') && (exams[i].getID() == exams[j].getID()))
                 {
                     r[index*2 + 1] = new Exam(exams[j].getFirstName(), exams[j].getLastName(), exams[j].getID(), 'f', exams[j].getScore());
                 }
             }
             index++;
         }
     }
     return r;    
 }
```

Output:

```
Sorted list: 
Exam [fn=Bill, ln=Gates, id=6, ex=m, score=90]
Exam [fn=Bill, ln=Gates, id=6, ex=f, score=96]
Exam [fn=James, ln=Gosling, id=3, ex=m, score=100]
Exam [fn=James, ln=Gosling, id=3, ex=f, score=100]
Exam [fn=Dennis, ln=Ritchie, id=5, ex=m, score=94]
Exam [fn=Dennis, ln=Ritchie, id=5, ex=f, score=100]
Exam [fn=Steve, ln=Jobs, id=9, ex=m, score=95]
Exam [fn=Steve, ln=Jobs, id=9, ex=f, score=91]
Exam [fn=Jeff, ln=Dean, id=7, ex=m, score=100]
Exam [fn=Jeff, ln=Dean, id=7, ex=f, score=100]
Exam [fn=Sergey, ln=Brin, id=22, ex=m, score=99]
Exam [fn=Sergey, ln=Brin, id=22, ex=f, score=97]
```

Comment: what part does not work?  I've added my output above.

Comment: Had to, he had it as a byte in his original code as part of "if (exams[i].getExamType() == 'm')" and all of the other examples from similar posts had it as a byte, so the string in the statement wouldn't have worked.  If for some reason he has his constructor truly as a string now, then that is easy enough to change.

Comment: Thank you @Michael very much! It's working. One last question: how many years of experience do you have with Java?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on char vs string in the constructor, no one had posted their pojo so I had created my own when working through other versions of this question.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED] @Michael,  your code is giving me this output with only one null:

```
    Sorted list: 
Bill Gates 6 midterm 90
Bill Gates 6 final 96
James Gosling 3 midterm 100
James Gosling 3 final 100
Sergey Brin 22 midterm 98
null
Dennis Ritchie 5 midterm 94
Dennis Ritchie 5 final 100
Steve Jobs 9 midterm 95
Steve Jobs 9 final 91
Jeff Dean 7 midterm 100
Jeff Dean 7 final 100
```

Here's the Exam class which has toString method:

```
class Exam {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int ID;
    private String examType;
    private int score;


    public Exam(String firstName, String lastName, int ID, String examType, int score)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.examType = examType;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return this.ID;
    }

    public char getExamType()
    {
        char examTypeCasted = 0;
        examTypeCasted = examType.charAt(0);
        return Character.toUpperCase(examTypeCasted);
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
        return this.score;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.ID + " " + this.examType + " " + this.score;
    }

    public boolean equals(Exam e)
    {
        if(this.equals(e))
            return true;
        else
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Jordan according to your output your are missing the last Sergey Brin entry which I believe is the last line in the file if I remember correctly.  Check your read loop

Answer (score 0):

These items which show **null** are never initialized thats why..

```
public class Example2 {

String array[] = new String[15];

public Example2(){

    for(int j=0; j<array.length-1; j++)
        array[j]="j";


    for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++)
        System.out.println(array[j]);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    new Example2();
}

}
```

*This example will print 14 ("J") and one null.Why? cause array[15] is not initialized.
So on your example with  i am sure that these items show **null** cause are never initialized.*